# bash script: word occurrences in web sites

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dns

I need to make a script that counts the word occurrences on the web pages

what I'm doing is calculating random IPs (avoiding checking the same ips more than once), using nmap to see if the port 80 is open to know if it's a web server and then I use w3m to make the http page as file.
After it's easy to count the word occurances

I got a few questions and problems

- This process takes A LOT, but I can't think any method to make it quicker
- Many of the ips with the port 80 open aren't web sites, they aren't up and they might have some problems, is there any ways to check only the sites that are up?
- this method only check the word occurrences in the index page of a web site, is there a way to check also the other public pages?

thanks a lot

Comment: With named-based virtual hosts, having the IP address isn't enough. You also need to know every DNS name that points to that IP. A single IP could be serving thousands of websites.

Comment: Sounds like you're planning to write a web scraper. A bash script may not be the best tool for the job. There are exisiting frameworks out there that will help you build one reasonably quickly, such as [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), [Heritrix](https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/display/Heritrix/Heritrix;jsessionid=423A366AA0AD45A45D0439A34E2C5A43) and many more. If you DO want to build one using a script, consider using [`wget`](http://www.dheinemann.com/2011/archiving-with-wget/).

Comment: thanks guys. First of all I need to make this script for my university, so it has to be in bash programming. Is there a way to get every DNS names for that ip? I know a lot of websites that offer this service. I tried also with "dig -x ipadress +short" and it gives me the domain name. The problem is that it's just one host. Is it enough? Because as you said a single ip can contain thousands of websites and with dig it gives me only one. Is there a linux command to do this? And also what about getting information of the other pages (not the index one)

Comment: @DomenicoToscani - dig -x gives the PTR record for an IP. There can only be one. DNS was not designed for this.

Comment: thanks, but is there any methods in bash to get something like this? http://www.webboar.com/ip/66.220.158.11 I've been really looking the whole day and can't find anything :(I tried dig, host, nslookup and they all give me the single PTR record, which I believe is not enough for what I'm trying to do or am I wrong?

Comment: They want you to build a network inventory and have restricted you to bash? They can ask you to play Beethoven's 9th on a kazoo, but they probably won't be pleased with the results of that either. Either you misunderstand your task or your supervisor does. Good luck.

Comment: maybe 'this script is for my university' means that it is class-work? If so, Domenico, it should be tagged as such. In any case, I'll really be surprised if there is a reasonable shell script solution to this problem. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I do similar stuff with awk. Awk is awesome for text parsing. What I do is analyze how many HTTP GETs each IP address done in the Apache log. So bots like yours would appear easily in my statistics :P With awk I've outperform all solutions made by all my collegues, in PHP, Ruby and bash script.

The problem is you are not generating statistics per file (or page). You are summing up all results, right? So I would use SQLite to keep track of how many times a word have appeared in all scanned texts. It is easy (and fast) to add data in SQLite with a shell script.

Also you should user wget --spider or other spider HTTP clients because they will download the content not only from the index page but from all pages that has links (HREFs) in the first page. So you can scan a website recursively.

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer correctly. I've covered all your topics:
 * Problems with performance? Use awk instead of bash script. It is faster than anything else for parsing text.
 * Instead of seeking port 80 open, do web crawling with real HTTP clients like wget and provide him a first website to access. It will sove you the problem of trying to analyze content in port 80 that is not actually web pages.
 * Also, using wget or other HTTP client with a recursive feature, you will be able to analyze all sub pages and links, not only the main page.